# Opencv How can I have smoother contours on curves?

Tags: opencv, contour, curve, smoothing

I'm facing some problems to get smoother contours on curves.
After an image processing I have this image.

[image]
I am trying to get smoother curves with this code:

```
imgWithBridgesBw = convert_to_bw(imgWithBridges)

# add later this mask upper
ellipsekernel20 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
enhanceMask = np.ones((InterholesBw.shape[0],InterholesBw.shape[1]) ,dtype="uint8") * 255
enhanceMaskColor = np.ones((InterholesBw.shape[0],InterholesBw.shape[1],3) ,dtype="uint8") * 255

# invert the Layer to get less blank pixels
imgWithBridgesBwInv = 255 - imgWithBridgesBw

imgWithBridgesBwInv_dilate = cv2.dilate(imgWithBridgesBwInv,ellipsekernel20,iterations =1)
imgWithBridgesBwInv_erode = cv2.erode(imgWithBridgesBwInv_dilate, ellipsekernel20, iterations = 1)  

_ ,allCnts, hier = cv2.findContours(imgWithBridgesBwInv_dilate,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(enhanceMask,allCnts,-1,0,2)
cv2.drawContours(enhanceMaskColor,allCnts,-1,(255,0,0),2)
```

The result is this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/testEhhancBwColor_.jpg

As you can see at this image, which is a "zoom", I'm not reaching any success.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with that? Do you want to anti-alias those lines? Try to draw the contour with line type `CV_AA`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "smooth"? Anti-aliasing or mathematical continuity?

Comment: Both @Abbondanza . I'd like to have only one line, instead of lot of small polygons,It's not a true curve..

Comment: You don't have _true_ curves in digital images ;D

Comment: @marco but it will never be a true curve. I will always be a lot of small "polygons". It only depends how much small they will be (minimal size is one pixel). You have basically two options - antialiasing or just simply gaussian blur

Comment: @kaspar could you tell me in your opinion what is the best option? After "smoothing" the curve I want to apply potrace or autotrace algorithm in order to vector the image. I know if I got a good bitmap, I'll have better arcs or belzier.